# Installing a version of Postgres (on an EC2 instance) that is not listed in Yum packages

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, postgresql

I'm trying to install Postgres on an EC2 instance, but `yum list` only includes version 9.2.24-1.amzn2.0.1.

My assumptive guess as to a possible next step is some kind of manual installation?

https://yum.postgresql.org/packages/ lists a whole lot of different versions, as well as different packages for each version depending on which Linux distribution it is being installed on.

At this point, my issue is two-fold:

1. Figuring out which Linux distribution AWS uses for default/standard AMIs (I'm using the first one that comes up with Free Tier options right now). I tried Googling a straightforward answer to this question, but all I can discern is that it is their own proprietary distro *somewhat* based on RHEL, or somehow *similar to* CentOS. I'm still not sure which particular Postgres package I'm supposed to install.
2. How to actually install the custom package. I haven't thoroughly researched this step yet since I'm still kinda stuck on step 1, and I figure that the result of step 1 might alter the substeps for step 2.

Comment: None of them. You're supposed to get rid of Amazon Linux. It's basically unsuitable for use by anyone for a variety of reasons, such as lack of compatibility (where you are now) and a long history of instability.

Comment: @MichaelHampton now that you mention that, I feel kind of stupid for not immediately considering using a different AMI from the get go. They have other distros available, some even free tier still. At the very least I can give that a go. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using RDS instead of managing your own postgresql?

Comment: @TomO'Connor, actually I have thought about it, and was planning to look into it eventually. I may end up pursuing that sooner than I had originally planned.

Comment: I'd really recommend it.  It shifts the burden of having to do the security updates and stuff back over to amazon's ballpark.